# Does the Gmail app automatically upload photos to Google Photos?

Tags: ios, gmail, google

Does the Gmail app on iPhone having access to your photo gallery automatically upload photos to Google Photos or Drive? Did any version of the Gmail app did this before if not now?

Answer (score 1):

No, the Gmail app does not upload your photos automatically. This can be done per your request if you choose to add a photo as an attachment to an email.

Comment: Did any prior version of the gmail app do so?

Comment: How can I check if a prior version did so?

Answer (score 0):

As Grgarside says the Gmail app does not do anything with photos, except being able to send photos as attachments.

But Google has a free app Google Photos which can auto upload all your photos to Google Photos cloud:
[image]